# Can anything done in a Haskell script be reproduced in a GHCi session?

Tags: haskell

I want to run the function

```
act :: IO(Char, Char)
act = do x <- getChar
         getChar
         y <- getChar
         return (x,y)
```

interactively in a GHCi session.  I've seen elsewhere that you can define a function in a session by using the semi-colon to replace a line-break.  However, when I write

```
act :: IO(Char, Char); act = do x <- getChar; getChar; y <- getChar; return (x,y)
```

it doesn't compile, saying

```
parse error on input ‘;’
```

I've elsewhere seen that `:{ ... }:` can be used for multiple line commands, but typing

```
:{ act :: IO(Char, Char)
```

and then hitting enter causes an error--perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to use them.

Besides just getting this particular case to work, is there a generic way of taking code that would run in a Haskell script and making it run in an interactive session?

Comment: Works for me.  The ability to do this without `let` was added somewhat recently... what version of ghc are you using?

Comment: As for `:{`, it has to be on its own line

Comment: (And the closer is `:}`, not `}:`.)

Comment: Does the single line one work if you surround the contents of the do-block with plain braces, that is `act = do { ... }`?

Comment: @luqui Yep, it was the version number, thought I had it up to date but my version controller gives me a pretty outdated one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't *just* insert semicolons to replace each line break. Doing stuff on one line means opting out of the [layout rule](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation), so you have to insert your own semicolons *and braces*. This means you need to know where those braces and semicolons would be required without the layout rule. For this case in particular, each `do` block needs braces around the whole block, and semicolons between each operation. The layout rule normally inserts these for you based on indentation.

So to write this specific example on one line, you can do this:

```
let act :: IO(Char, Char); act = do {x <- getChar; getChar; y <- getChar; return (x,y)}
```

On a new enough version of ghci you can omit the `let` as well.

For simple enough `do` blocks you might even get away with omitting the braces. In your example there's only one place the `{` and `}` could possibly go, and so GHCI inserts them even when you do everything on one line. But for an expression with multiple `do` blocks or other multiline constructs, you will need to insert them explicitly if you want them on one line.

Comment: Worth noting that `let` is also a layout keyword as it takes a block of bindings, so `do { let x = 1; y = 2; pure (x, y) }` is invalid—you need `do { let { x = 1; y = 2 }; pure (x, y) }`.

Comment: The general rule is that indenting in is equivalent to a "virtual `{`", and indenting out is equivalent to "virtual `}`"s, one for every open layout level you indent out of.

Answer (score 0):

On the broader question:

> Besides just getting this particular case to work, is there a generic way of taking code that would run in a Haskell script and making it run in an interactive session?

The closest thing I know of is using the [multiline delimiters](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:%7B), "`:{` and `:}` (each on a single line of its own)". They can handle almost anything you can throw at them. They *can't* handle imports (GHCi does support the full import syntax, but each import must be on its own in a line) and pragmas (the only alternative is `:set`, which also need a line all of its own), which means you can't help but separate them from the rest of the code and enter them beforehand.

(You can always save the code somewhere and load the file with `:l`, and that will often turn out to be the more convenient option. Still, I have a soft spot for `:{` and `:}` -- if I want no more than trying out half a dozen lines of impromptu code with no context, I tend to open a text editor window, write the little snippet and paste it directly in GHCi.)